# Detect which is faulty between SSD and motherboard

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, ssd, motherboard

Windows 7 started giving me some problems, like disabling the Aero theme, not letting me open the screen resolution options, etc.

Now, I'm pretty sure my SSD (OCZ Vertex 3) is faulty, the S.M.A.R.T. tool always shows some I/O error and the SSD temp at 128°C.

But I thought that it can also be the motherboard (ASUS P8P67 PRO), maybe for some unknown reason the SATA3 port is not working as expected.

Is there a way to detect which is faulty between the SSD and the Motherboard?

Comment: Is there any reason to believe the SSD temp being at 128°C? Is this a laptop or desktop PC? If the latter, can you, when the PC is powered off for a couple of minutes, disconnect and reconnect the SATA cable (to clean the connections), or replace the SATA cable?

Comment: @AndrewMorton It's a desktop pc, ans AFAIK the 128°C temperature is a fake temp shown due to missing temperature sensors in the ssd. i'll try disconnecting and reconnecting the sata cable

Comment: `SATA3 port is not working as expected` you could test this by plugging it into a different SATA port and testing it